# Помогите сделать так что бы при наведении два разных элемента внутри были разными цветами

Tags: html, css

Помогите сделать так что бы при наведении на `<li>` (или на `<a>`) стрелочка становилась красной, т.е. там бордеры меняют цвет, а текст должен быть синим.

```css
li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-align-items: baseline;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadbdd;
}

.arrow {
  border-top: 2px solid #dadbdd;
  border-right: 2px solid #dadbdd;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45grad);
}
```

```html
<li><i class="arrow"></i><a href="#">Судові інженерно-технічні експертизи</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
li a{
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
li{
  cursor:pointer;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-align-items: baseline;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #dadbdd;
}
.arrow{
  border-top: 2px solid #dadbdd;
  border-right: 2px solid #dadbdd;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45grad);
}

li:hover .arrow{
  border-color: red;
}

li:hover a{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<li><i class = "arrow"></i><a href="#">Судові інженерно-технічні експертизи</a></li>
```

Comment: Парень ты или девушка, скажу одно, дай Бог тебе здоровья, работа уже 10 час подряд, уже голова не соображает, реально большое спасибо))())

Comment: @dmitriyzubkov пометь тогда ответ хотяб за правильный

Comment: @dmitriyzubkov, в SO нет пола, только товарищ помощник! :) P. S. Примите ответ (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: там 6 минут ограничение, я бы пометил, мне не в лом))

Comment: 2 минуты осталось)